# Chromedriver crashed after patching

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I wrote a Java code that patches Crhome Driver by replacing the $cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_ to $abc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_ to avoid automation detection when using Selenium.

When I check the output file I see that the only change is in that string (I verified using diff).

However, after running Selenium chromedriver crashes:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'Nikolas-MacBook-Pro-2.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:10fc:9205:ef69:8927%en0'
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:71)
    at org.example.PatchedChromeDriver.main(PatchedChromeDriver.java:60)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '12.5', java.version: '17.0.5'
Driver info: driver.version: PatchedChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:98)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    ... 6 more
```

And this is the method that I use to patch the driver:

```
private static void patchDriver(String chromeDriverPath) throws IOException {
        Path executablePath = Paths.get(chromeDriverPath);
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(executablePath);

        // Convert the byte array to a character array
        char[] charBuffer = new char[fileContent.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i++) {
            charBuffer[i] = (char) fileContent[i];
        }

        // Replace the tracker pattern with the replacement string
        String content = new String(charBuffer);
        System.out.println(content);
        content = content.replace("$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_", "$abc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_");
        System.out.println(content);

        charBuffer = content.toCharArray();
        fileContent = new byte[charBuffer.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < charBuffer.length; i++) {
            fileContent[i] = (byte) charBuffer[i];
        }

        // Write the patched content to the executable path
        Files.write(executablePath, fileContent);
    }
```

When I use my code without the patching, it runs fine. But with patching chromedriver crashes. Why?